# Filling a circle doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I was working with the canvas API, but when working with CanvasRenderingContext2D.arc(x,y,radius,startAngle,endAngle,couterclockwise) which mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) that it takes the following arguments:

> x: The horizontal coordinate of the arc's center.

> y: The vertical coordinate of the arc's center.

> radius: The arc's radius. Must be positive.

> startAngle: The angle at which the arc starts in radians, measured from the positive x-axis.

> endAngle: The angle at which the arc ends in radians, measured from the positive x-axis.

> counterclockwise Optional: An optional boolean value. If true, draws the arc counter-clockwise between the start and end angles. The default is false (clockwise)

I found that when for example I am setting the startAngle to 0 and endAngle 1.5*MathPI and fill the circle it gives a segment and not 3/4 of a circle as I was expecting. I am trying to find a way to use it to make portions of a circuit not a segment but with no hope.

here is the code

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
resizeCanvas();

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, Math.PI * 3 / 2, false);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
```

The output
[image]

I was expecting output to be a 3/4 of a circle starting from 0 to 3/2*PI.
I just want to know how to use the canvas API to make my expected ouput.

Comment: It seems like the HTML canvas is working exactly as expected – just not the way you want it to work. The Canvas uses SVG-like instructions for drawing. Essentially, you are drawing 3/4 of an arc. Next, you are telling it to fill in the arc, but it's not a closed path, so it will automatically close it for you. When a path is has a separate starting and ending point, to automatically close the path, it just connects the starting and ending points, resulting in the output above.

Comment: ... my suggestion is to draw a full circle, then draw a white triangle to block out a portion of the circle

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, I am new to using canvas and I didn't know  about this behavior that my code will not create a close path bur rather will be closed automatically, as this helped me to reach the answer. I was thinking that it will stop at the end angle and then come back to the center of the circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that when using

```
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, Math.PI * 3/2, false);
```

this will create an arc between two points as the name suggest (ctx.arc) and when we fill the shape: it will connect the startAngle point to the endAngle Point. and fill this shape. And to see this, we can use the stroke style and stroke method to see the output and it will be something like that
[image]

This after changing the code as follows:

```
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, Math.PI * 3/2, false);
// ctx.lineTo(100,100);
// ctx.closePath();

ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.stroke();
```

To make a 3/4 of a circle, we need to draw a line from the endAngle to the center and then close the path to the start angle.

we can do this as follows:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, Math.PI * 3/2, false);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill();
```

and this will have a 3/4 of a circle as shown below.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
resizeCanvas();

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, Math.PI * 3 / 2, false);
ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
```

[image]

Comment: I edited your answer to add a runnable snippet, so that others can run your code in your answer to demonstrate the solution. It's worth pointing out that this code - in my browser, Firefox and Chrome - seems to create a red quarter-circle where the cut-out portion should sit.

Comment: You are right, I just mistakenly set the counterClockwise to true which will make 1/4 of circcle in the counter clockwise. I edited it to false. It should now work.